# 'Aw, Snap!' Error when inspecting element in Chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome, error-handling

Whenever I inspect any element that's part of my navigation menu, OR inspect element and then browse to a navigation menu I get the 'Aw, Snap' error in Google Chrome. I figured there must be something wrong with the source but after reviewing the source in an editor it seems as though everything is correct in format.

What might be causing this error?

You can [Click Here](http://blacktiephotographers.com) to view the site :)

## Update:

Something in this code here is causing the error:

```
<li>
    <a id="nav-corporate" class="accordionButton <?php if (is_page(1635) || is_page(1909)) { echo "curr-page-nav";}?>">Corporate</a>
<div class="sub-list-container">

    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="<?php echo get_page_link(1635); ?>" id="nav-meeting" class="subitem"><span class="nav-hidden">Meetings</span></a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="<?php echo get_page_link(1909); ?>" id="nav-event" class="subitem"><span class="nav-hidden">Events</span></a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    </div>
    </li>
```

I have tried on three computers by the way.

Comment: Confirmed for Chrome 20.0.1132.57 on 64-bit Linux.

Comment: When I reload the page after getting the `Aw, Snap` error, I am able to inspect any element in the nav bar without getting any error.

Comment: It's probably in your javascript and not your HTML. I removed all HTML but the navigation menu and it still had the error.

Comment: I thought so too, I removed all of the <script> tags from the page through Chrome's inspect element, but same issue.

Comment: Hmm, I got "Aw, snap!" first time I visited the site – now I can't reproduce it?

Comment: @Marcus - close dev. tools and refresh browser and you will

Comment: @Evan – yepp, you are correct. "Thanks" =) Really, really odd error...

Comment: This question is about Chrome, right? It didn't say that in the title, body, or tags, but i infer that from the comments. It really helps to make that clear. You won't get any help from Firefox gurus who come across this question! I've edited it accordingly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem appears to be an issue with your [style.css](http://blacktiephotographers.com/wp-content/themes/photolux_v120/style.css) file.  In that file, you have:

```
/*::selection {
    background: #666; /* Safari */
    color: #FFF;
}

::-moz-selection {
    background: #666; /* Firefox */
    color: #FFF;
}*/
```

What's happening is you have a comment `/* Safari */` within a broader comment around the entire snippet above, which is closing the broader comment prematurely and causing a parse error for the CSS.  Google Chrome is choking on the malformed CSS file, which is causing the "Aw, snap!" error to occur when inspecting elements.

Removing the `/* Safari */` comment won't fix that problem, as the `/* Firefox */` below it causes the same issue.

**EDIT:** While that did fix a minor issue with the CSS, it wasn't the whole solution.  In light of [thakis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/551986/thakis)' answer below, fixing the following style does prevent the crashing when inspecting elements:

```
#navigation-menu-container{
  border-image:  url(images/shadow-border.png) 10 stretch;
}
```

Compare [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/saluce/twkVp/), which is a copy/paste of the site code in question (all `head` tags and relevant html markup), with [the corrected fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/saluce/twkVp/6/), in which the `style.css` markup has been imported into the fiddle and the `#navigation-menu-container` rule has been changed to the above code, and you'll see that the fiddle page doesn't crash.

Comment: I will try this, but would like to note that I get the error regardless of whether or not the dev. window is open. You may want to check on that again.

Comment: Update: I removed all <script> tags from the main page, also removed a lot of the html - did this all through dev. tools "elements" tab - still get the same error.

Comment: Interesting.  I'm on version 21.0.1180.60, I wonder if that makes a difference.  I know it was only erroring out on me with the dev window closed, but there might be something else besides that.  If you are getting the error with it open or close, then test however way you can guarantee generating the error every time.

Comment: I'm also using version 21.0.1180.60, very odd indeed. I think if you close out of the dev. tools window, then refresh the page, then try your test again you will see it bug out regardless.

Comment: It's not JavaScript, because the error is still happening after disabling JavaScript.

Comment: Excellent point. check out my latest "update" by the way - checking on the html now.

Comment: It looks like you've removed the navigation menu from the live site...I'm not getting the error now.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15005/discussion-between-saluce-and-evan)

Answer (score 4):

When chrome crashes, please file a bug at http://new.crbug.com so that the chrome developers can fix the problem. (I've filed http://crbug.com/141139 for this issue for you). Ideally, try making a copy of your site and keep removing things from the copy until you have a small test case that still reproduces the problem. Then attach that to the bug.

Edit: Looks like this bit from your style.css causes it:

```
#navigation-menu-container{
  border-image:  url(images/shadow-border.png) stretch 10;
}
```

`border-image` needs its numbers in front of `stretch` (see e.g. http://css-tricks.com/understanding-border-image/), and Chrome gets confused by that not being the case. Moving the `10` in front of `stretch` fixes the crash (but the crash is still a chrome bug of course).