# Google Chrome Devtools crashes when inspecting element in page containing kendo-ui styles

Tags: css, google-chrome, kendo-ui, google-chrome-devtools

Ever since a couple of weeks ago I have encountered crashes with the Chrome Developer Tools. Whenever inspecting an element on the page I get the "Aw, Snap!" Error page, and a message on the devTools panel say "DevTools was disconnected from the page". After reading [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11811313/aw-snap-error-when-inspecting-element-in-chrome) post I have managed to isolate the css file that is causing the error. It turns out to be a kendo-ui css file `/Content/kendo/2015.2.902/kendo.silver.min.css`. When commenting out the file, the devTools works fine and I can inspect the elements.

I ran this file in [CSS Validator](https://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator) and it gave me 6 errors (like `Unknown pseudo-element or pseudo-class ::selection [selection]` and `Too many values or values are not recognized : inset 0 0 0 1px inset 0 0 3px 1px #bebec3`) and 116 warning (like `Property none,-webkit-gradient(linear,left top,left bottom,from(rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.45)),to(rgba(255, 255, 255, 0))) is an unknown vendor extension` and `Property -webkit-box-shadow is an unknown vendor extension`)

I have several projects working with kendo-ui, and removing them is not an option nor modify the css files of kendo, and I also don't want to stop working with the beloved Chrome devTools.

My Chrome version is `48.0.2564.103 m`.
I have tried tweaking the settings of the devTools, maybe make it less strict but no luck.

Any ideas how to resolve this?

**Update 1**

I gave it a try and modified the `kendo.silver.min.css` file and removed all the errors found at the css-validator (still have 115 warnings, but removing them is the same as not loading the file at all). The css validation turns ok. Running the application again with the modified file gave no results, and the devtools keeps crushing when inspecting an element. It seems to be crushing when inspecting an element that is a child of a Kendo control such as grid, tab strip etc, but **not** for standalone elements even if they have a `k-...` css classes.

This issue can be reproduced at the [kendo ui demos site itsef](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/editing-inline). When right clicking on one of the buttons in the grid and trying to `Inspect` it.

Comment: A couple things to try.
1.  It appears you restructured your Kendo libraries on the hdd.  I know Kendo used to look in specific places for these files, so you could try arranging them back to how they were when you installed them.
2.  You're running a version that is about a year old.  If it's possible, I always try to update to the latest version if I find a problem I can't solve.

Comment: @Ageonix, the kendo libraries are placed in my mvc project the way the installer placed them. what do you mean arranging them back? as for updating to last version, I cant, since my licence expired last year. I don't think it matters much since it a stable version.

Comment: Hmm, ok.  Now that you mention it (and since @XEstebanN mentioned it as well), during the last couple of weeks, several of our customers have reported major slowdown and sometimes complete crashes in the browser on pages using Kendo.  I thought it was because I upgraded to the latest version, but it sounds like you haven't so I don't know how they could be related.

Comment: Guys, this issue is related to the latest version of Chrome - we also started experiencing it after the last update. I would suggest to report this issue directly to the Chrome (e.g.: https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95315?hl=en). 
Chrome DevTools also won't let us set breakpoints on certain lines and I'm forced to use firefox for debugging until this issue is fixed (we are heavily debugging DOM / CSS / JavaScript everyday).

Comment: @Issac It seems to be working fine for me in Chrome Dev channel on linux.  Here is the screenshot http://imgur.com/WgWwJXT

Comment: It looks like known issues with custom CSS property: http://crbug.com/583300. It was fixed and merged to current beta.

Comment: Could you check in current beta (https://www.google.com/chrome/browser/beta.html)?

Comment: @RamanaVenkata it seams that the crushes happen only in some of the Kendo themes. `Silver` for exmple will crush the devtools but `Black` theme will work just fine.

Comment: @AlexeyKozyatinskiy, I have installed the beta version as you suggested and the devtools if working just fine. No crushes when inspecting elements. The Chrome version is `49.0.2623.39 beta-m (64-bit)`. Checked it on my local machine project, on a production website and on the kendo demos website. I guess this the the solution (even if temporary until the next chrome update), so please  post it as an answer and I will accept it. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is known [issue](http://crbug.com/583300) in current chrome stable version (48). It was fixed and merged to chrome 49.
Please use [beta](http://google.com/chrome/browser/beta.html) before Chrome 49 will become stable.